How to interpret "to practice" in "bring to practice"?
Since English is not my native language, I am very interested in how to interpret "to practice" in the following English interrogative sentence. I'd like to know which option below is grammatically correct.

What do you bring to practice?


It is common to think of the word "practice" as a noun.
It is common to think of "to practice" as an infinitive.
Both of the two interpretations are equally common.

Which option is correct seems especially important in the following situation. For example, let's assume that a person brings a doll to every soccer practice (to the practice location). If you interpret the above question using #1, you can include "a doll" in the answer. However, if you interpret the above question using #2, you cannot include "a doll" in the answer, because "a doll" is irrelevant to the purpose of soccer practice.

In British English, practice is always a noun when spelled with a second 'c' rather than 's'.

'Practice' here is the noun, with 'to practice' a prepositional phrase rather than a to-infinitive.
One can compare related fixed phrases such as

brought to light
brought to his senses
brought to book.

(A counterexample is 'brought to bear [on something]').
Examples found on the internet are:


All are innovative medical devices that represent the best of biomedical engineering ideas brought to practice .... [NIH National
Library of Medicine]

... own ideas brought to practice can be a real stimulus ... [Fostering Creativity and Innovation ... ; Albert R. C. Westwood and
Yukiko Sekine; Research Technology Management;
jstor]

... ideas brought to practice. For this reason he preferred virtues over values, because virtues encompassed action/thinking .... [The
Writings of Gadamer; Heather Sharp and Niklas Ammert; Sage
Journals]



The expression is close in meaning to 'put into practice' but (1) is more formal and rarer and (2) hints more at a structure (think of a medical practice) wherein the application is made, the new technique say introduced.
....................
I deliberately didn't stress the spelling variants (practice vs practise). In the US, the verb is more usually 'practice' [M-W]; thinking this usage is a spelling mistake is itself a mistake. So mere morphological analysis can't distinguish which intercategorial polyseme is in play.

of course in speech, there is no difference (in modern English) between the sound of "practice" and "practise".  Using "c" instead of "s" is such a common spelling mistake, it might also be treated as a non-standard variant.

I deliberately didn't stress the spelling variants. In the US, the verb is more usually 'practice' [M-W]; thinking this is a spelling mistake is itself a mistake.

Those examples are over-intellectual in the sense of soccer practice or musical practice. I agree they are not to infinitives, though.

I've tried to point out that 'brought to practice' in the sense it is usually encountered is not the less idiom-orientated 'bring along to a soccer practice'. In the UK at least, 'I've brought my shin pads / own piano scores along to the practice' would be far more usual for this prosaic situation. 'Put into practice' similarly doesn't refer to a sports or music practice session.

https://laura-bradshaw-yoga.mailerpage.io/faqs
Q: What do I need to bring to practise?
A: A mat, a bottle of water are essential. If you have your own props you like to use (blocks, straps, blankets) then please bring them.
This 'to practise(AmE:to practice)' is obviously a to-infinitive.
I guess the option 3 is right.
At least, this sentence is grammatically correct.

I am afraid this question is not about "to practise." I would like to know how native English speakers would interpret "to practice", not "to practise".  I assume from your handle that you are Japanese like me, but I would like to hear what native speakers think. Also, pointing out that there is a usage does not prove that it is as common as some other usage.

To a native speaker is is not 'obviously a to-infinitive', just a spelling mistake for the noun  practice (session).
