The usage of 'to practice'
https://laura-bradshaw-yoga.mailerpage.io/faqs
Q: What do I need to bring to practise?

A: A mat, a bottle of water are essential. If you have your own props you like to use (blocks, straps, blankets) then please bring them.

This "to practise(AmE:to practice)" is obviously a to-infinitive not a prepositional phrase judging from the spelling.
I think it means "to have a yoga-practice".
(AmE:"practice" for both noun and verb)
(BrE:"practise" for verb,"practice" for noun)
Is this usage of "to practice(BrE:to practise)" somewhat anomalous?
Or is it normal?

I have such a question because I have read the following Q&A.
https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/353263/　
According to it,it is common to take the word "practice" in "bring to practice" as a noun.
But this case should not be done so.

Thank you.

It's ambiguous is speech for everyone, and also in writing for American English (they write practice for both noun and verb). In British English and other varieties (including those used in Canada, Australia, and other places), a distinction is made between the verb the noun form by varying the spelling: the noun is spelled practice (just like in American English) and the verb is spelled practise. There's nothing "anomalous" about spelling reflecting speech.

It's not a to-infinitive, practice is the noun. Practice is the thing/place to which you are bringing things.

Is this 'pactise'  a misspelling of 'practice'?

The word "practice" in "Where do you practice?" is an intransitive verb. Can "Where do you practice?" be paraphrased into "Which place do you use to practice?" ? If it is possible,isn't this "to practice" a to-infinitive? Isn't the phrase "to practise" above the same?

Where do you practice? ... Where does he practice? In both cases practice doesn't change, because it's an (unmarked, without the infinitive marker to) infinitive. It's the "active" verb to do that's being inflected for second / third person you do / he does (inverted when used to form a question).

I know that.I want to point out that the word "practice" in "Where do you practice?" is not a noun and it means "have a practice".

I'm afraid it seems that the intent of my question is not being understood clearly.I don't intend to change 'practice' to 'practise' or vice versa,but the infinitive to the to-infinitive maintain the meaning of "have a yoga-practice".

It is not "obviously a to-infinitive" to a native speaker. The question asks what things should be brought to a practice session. The writer has mistakenly used the spelling with 's' which is used for the verb in British English.

I'd interpret it as Kate does - it could technically mean "what do I need to bring (in order) to practise", but the noun is so much more idiomatic in this context that I'd take it as a misspelling.

I understand.This case must be a spelling mistake.Thank you all very much.

But the writer correctly distinguishes between "practice" and "practise" on the following page.
https://laura-bradshaw-yoga.mailerpage.io/about

And she has a BSc in Natural Sciences (Neuroscience and Psychology) from UCL.

I asked the author directly, 'What do you think about some people claiming this is a spelling mistake?'

I received a response from her.She says this is not a spelling mistake.She says that this 'to practise' has been written to mean 'in order to practise the practice of yoga' .
